# Tengo tres variables de tipo number con valores distintos ¿Como imprimir en consola el candidato "A" y candidato "B" tienen los puntajes mas altos

Tags: javascript

```js
const candidatoUno = "Marcelo Sosa";
const candidatoDos = "Alan Sosa";
const candidatoTres = "Alicia Villalba";

let totalVotosCandidatoUno = 60;
let totalVotosCandidatoDos = 20;
let totalVotosCandidatoTres = 50;
let array = [totalVotosCandidatoUno,totalVotosCandidatoDos,totalVotosCandidatoTres];
let top1 
let top2 
let c1 = candidatoUno;
let c2 = candidatoDos;

for (let i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
  array.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b;
  });
  let top1 = array[1];
  let top2 = array[2];
  console.log(top1);
  console.log(top2);
  

  if (top1 == totalVotosCandidatoUno) {
    console.log(`${candidatoUno} pasa al repechaje `)
    let c1 = candidatoUno;
  } else if (top1 == totalVotosCandidatoDos) {
    console.log(`${candidatoDos} pasa al repechaje `)
    let c1 = candidatoDos;
  }else{
    console.log(`${candidatoTres} pasa al repechaje `)
    let c1 = candidatoTres;
  }
  
  if (top2 == totalVotosCandidatoUno) {
    console.log(`${candidatoUno} pasa al repechaje `)
    let c2 = candidatoUno;
  } else if (top2 == totalVotosCandidatoDos) {
    console.log(`${candidatoDos} pasa al repechaje `)
    let c2 = candidatoDos;
  }else{
    console.log(`${candidatoTres} pasa al repechaje `)
    let c2 = candidatoTres;
    
  }
  console.log(`El candidato ${c1} con ${top1} votos y el candidato ${c2} con ${top2} votos iran al repechaje `)
  }
```

*Buenas tardes gente estoy en mi primer semestre de Analisis de sistemas en la universidad y tengo la siguiente tarea de pseudocodigo*

Caso 2:  Si no se logra un ganador, van a la segunda vuelta los 2 candidatos que tengan los mayores puntajes

*Ya pude resolver el caso uno ahora voy por el caso dos, estube tratando de resolver el caso 2 y el codigo funciona bien hasta una parte pero al ir cambiando los valores de los votos totales para testear que funcione bien no me coincide el valor de los votos totales con el nombre del candidato correcto   *

Comment: Hola Marcelo, tu código tiene unos problemines, declarás `let top1`, `let top2`, `let c1 = candidatoUno;`, `let c2 = candidatoDos;`, y después para usarlas escribís `let....` osea creas otras variables que enmascaran a las originales, hay otro error muy menor, `let top1 = array[1];` y  `let top2 = array[2];`  están invertidos, `array[2]` contiene el número mayor, quitando los `let` que están de más e invirtiendo los valores de `top1` y `top2` tu código funciona de maravilla!!!.

Comment: Gracias a quién re-abrió la pregunta, si fue el mismo que la cerró, aparte van mis felicitaciones... equivocarse es humano, corregir es de sabios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como dije en los comentarios, el problema grave, era re-declarar las variables, ya que se crea una variable nueva, con la que se opera, y luego se le piden los datos a la otra, que no fué modificada.

```js
const candidatoUno = "Marcelo Sosa";
const candidatoDos = "Alan Sosa";
const candidatoTres = "Alicia Villalba";

let totalVotosCandidatoUno = 60;
let totalVotosCandidatoDos = 20;
let totalVotosCandidatoTres = 50;
let array = [ totalVotosCandidatoUno, totalVotosCandidatoDos, totalVotosCandidatoTres ];

   // eliminamos las siguientes declaraciones 
// let top1; 
// let top2; 

   // las siguientes dos asignaciones, ayudaron a enmascarar el problema
   // si no las hubieses hecho, habrías obtenido un "undefined" que te hubiese guiado
let c1 = candidatoUno;
let c2 = candidatoDos;

   // quitamos el for que no tiene sentido
//    for( let i = 1; i < array.length; i++ ) {
  array.sort( function( a, b ) {
    return a - b;
  });

     // invertimos las asignaciones
  let top1 = array[ 2 ];
  let top2 = array[ 1 ];
  console.log( top1 );
  console.log( top2 );  

     // le quitamos el "let" a "c1" y a "c2"
  if( top1 == totalVotosCandidatoUno ) {
    console.log( `${candidatoUno} pasa al repechaje` )
    c1 = candidatoUno;
  }
  else if (top1 == totalVotosCandidatoDos) {
    console.log(`${candidatoDos} pasa al repechaje`)
    c1 = candidatoDos;
  }
  else{
    console.log(`${candidatoTres} pasa al repechaje`)
    c1 = candidatoTres;
  }
  
  if( top2 == totalVotosCandidatoUno ) {
    console.log( `${candidatoUno} pasa al repechaje` )
     c2 = candidatoUno;
  } 
  else if( top2 == totalVotosCandidatoDos ) {
    console.log( `${candidatoDos} pasa al repechaje` )
    c2 = candidatoDos;
  }
  else {
    console.log( `${candidatoTres} pasa al repechaje` )
    c2 = candidatoTres;
    
  }
  console.log( `El candidato ${c1} con ${top1} votos y el candidato ${c2} con ${top2} votos iran al repechaje` )
//    }
```